# The search results in Drupal includes HTML Entities. How can I have a clean output?

Tags: html, search, drupal, entities

How can I have a clean html ouput for search result pages? Each time I try to include special characters like "&" as part of the search term, I usually get results with "&" highlighted yet includes the HTML entity. Thus, the results has &,   " etc...Here's a screenshot sample - http://min.us/mt3rOV5zVtOh6

Meanwhile, when I do my searches with "&" included in the search term, the result yields to having a clean output.

The piece of code in search-result.tpl.php

http://pastebin.com/zCmMJLNh

I've already tried several decoding functions but no success. Been trying to fix this for days already. The site is using Drupal 6 and the search module has been overridden.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, you could try [drupal_html_to_text](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes--mail.inc/function/drupal_html_to_text/7) to convert the snippet into plain text.

The right way is probably to figure out why those results aren't getting converted. Based on your comments it looks like the problem is only when you search specifically for "&". More specifically, it's the regex in the search.module (/modules/search/search.module - line 1188 in 6):

```
preg_match_all('/ ("([^"]+)"|(?!OR)([^" ]+))/', ' '. $keys, $matches);
```

It only matches spaces before the keyword (not after). You could modify the $keys here like:

```
if ($keys == '&') $keys = '&amp;'
```

Or something like that (of course that means hacking core - meh).

You could also possibly add a form_alter via a module and modify the search form (see this link on [how to add the form_alter](http://bitnr.drupalgardens.com/content/practical-application-hookformalter-taming-advanced-search-taxonomy-splat)). Then you could [add a custom submit handler](http://kyleyu.com/?q=node/129) which would alter the search term in the form before it is submitted.

Comment: Hi! I've tried drupal_html_to_text but here's what I've got -http://min.us/mZsHkh9zx101c. those words enclosed with * are the bold ones included in the search terms.  The snippets are just from nodes. I'm not using Solr. 

Is there a way to fix it before the user hit the search button? Say, "&" will be replaced by "&_a_m_p;"? Thanks!

Comment: I updated my comment to include some advice based on your screenshot. I think it is fixable (but annoying).

Comment: hey hross. Sorry for this very late response but I have been doing something else. I have never solved this since I'm a not good at PHP. But now I'm doing this, I've taken your advice and studying things now. I'm thinking now of just ignoring the & in search terms. But still looking for some tutorials. If you are still available to help or anyone who would like to, can you please provide me a simple code that I could follow and hook in my Drupal. Thank you a lot!

Answer (score 1):

You say "...the search module has been overridden" this could be the cause of why the search snippet remains htmlentityencoded on output ( e.g check_plain'd escaped html )

A better fix would be to find the cause in the modification, e.g a preprocess function that modifies the search snippet ( if any )

Alternatively, you could probably run the $snippet through decode_entities

i.e `print decode_entities($snippet)`

Assuming, the html is already escaped, as if not, can be a security risk.

See also: http://php.net/manual/en/function.html-entity-decode.php
and: http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.htmlspecialchars-decode.php

Comment: Hi! David. thanks for your response. Unfortunately, I can't find any preprocess functions to $snippet. Yet, adding decode_entities did not also solve the issue. I've also used html_entity_decode, check_plain, htmlentities, htmlspecialchars_decode. I tried to search in Drupal.org and also see the same issue. See http://min.us/mrBM2fPqRRk96

Comment: The default search doesn't have the issue you mentioned above, so I think the solution must be in studying whatever modifications you have to search and working from there.